# Log4J Could not find classpath

Tags: java, log4j, websphere, classpath

I am using WebSphere 9 , while uploading ear using admin console its stuck quite long time and in the background its giving below error

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
[24/12/22 13:42:57:505 IST] 00000143 SystemErr     R javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
```

i almost tried everything that , is there anything that I need to pass in jvm argument

like we have **DSDMSConfig.build.date=12/17/2022 -DloggingFlush=true**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That _sounds_ like problems with the filesystem being used to store the uploaded ear. I'd get somebody to check that filesystem from an OS prompt.